# Sphinx: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed

Tags: linux, rpm, sphinx

Can't find a way to install sphinx. It's asking for libmysqlclient.so.15, which I have...
What else can i do?

This is what I've tried already

```
[root@server1 ~]# rpm -ivh sphinx-2.0.3-1.el5.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) is needed by sphinx-2.0.3-1.rhel5.x86_64
        libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by sphinx-2.0.3-1.rhel5.x86_64

[root@server3 hooks]# ls -l /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Jun 29 09:57 /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.18
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1474856 Dec 24 01:37 /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jun 29 09:57 /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18 -> libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6853576 May 11  2011 /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
[root@server3 hooks]# ls -l /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jan 12  2010 /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so -> /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dec 24 12:18 /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15 -> /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Dec 24 12:22 /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18 -> libmysqlclient.so.15
```

Answer (score 2):

according to a post in the [sphinx forum](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=8564) try the follwing:

> Try installing the [Mysql-shared-compat](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/11455444/dir/redhat_el_5/com/MySQL-shared-compat-6.0.9-0.rhel5.i386.rpm.html) if there is one
>
> install the old centos 5 mysqlclient15 rpm from [remi](http://dev.antoinesolutions.com/remi-repository) to make
>   this work.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot but didn't get any solution for libmysqlclient.so.15 problem. According to [this page](http://devw3.com/linux/missing-dependency-libmysqlclient-so-15-while-installing-sphinx-search-server) the only solution is to install from source.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.